# Malicious software removal tool reports hundreds of infections and finally finds nothing

Tags: windows, security, virus, malware, anti-virus

I have downloaded the Malicious software removal tool from the Microsoft website, and got the November 2017 edition, which obviously is the latest one available. During Quick analyse, the tool reports several hundreds of infected files it found, and finally, when scanning is finished, it reporsts that nothing was found. Is that a bug in the software, or what exactly is the tool trying to tell me? I have added some screenshots (in German language unfortunately only, since this is my system locale). But I can reproduce that behaviour on all of my systems.

You can download the tool here:
https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/malicious-software-removal-tool-details.aspx

[image: During scan, 252 infected files are reported]
[image: After scan is finished, no onfection is found]
[image: Detail view telling nothing was found]

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same result with the November MRT.exe as you reported above, (not in a quick scan, I need to scan the entire c: drive).  My Quick scan report no File Infected, but when I scan C: or my system I get:
    Files scanned: 10412706
    File Infected: 1007
But then when it completes (is finished) the MRT.exe returns the standard:
     “No Malicious software was detected.”

So, I downloaded the MRT.exe (Nov) again manually (a new copy) and the tool continues to report in the same manor.

“Full Scan(s)” by Windows Defender (both online and offline) and the free version of Malwayerbytes  do not find any infected files.

At this point, I’m waiting for the December version of MRT.exe (tomorrow) and will see if “Dec” MRT.exe continues to report issues (files infected).

So I can confirm your report, but also don’t understand what is occurring.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cb8Q.png)
... john

Answer (score 0):

After getting persistent malware, it may be impossible to remove it while the PC is booted from the infected HDD. You may need to boot from *external media* (z.b. USB flash drive or CD) and use the anti-malware tools from there.

Though I do not know if the Malicious Software Removal Tool can run from [WinPE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613860.aspx), there are a number of other malware removal tools that can make bootable rescue disks (or flash media), such as [Avira Rescue System](https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system), [Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10](https://support.kaspersky.com/4162), [Avast! rescue media](https://support.avast.com/en-us/article/114/) and [AVG Rescue CD](https://www.avg.com/en-us/download.prd-arl). The rescue media should be created just before use so that it has the most recent virus definitions.

In worst case, the malware cannot be eliminated without *complete reformatting* the HDD (or SSD) and restoring from the last *known good* image... which is why it is important to keep multiple separate disk images, in case the most recent also is infected.

Comment: Did you read the inital post? THe topic is that there actually is no malware present, it's only that tool reporting malware during scan, but not after the scan is finished!

Comment: To me, that means it's unclear if the malware is there or not. If the tool reports it, and then unsuccessfully tries to clear it, one cannot be sure that the Malicious Software Removal Tool was not disabled during the attempted scan.

Comment: So did you actually try to run this tool on your own systems? That happens to me on every PC I try...

Comment: Nope, I've never had the Malicious Software Removal Tool find *anything*, though I let it run on initial purchase and monthly on the updates. Perhaps the third-party AV software on my PC's is effective?